# get value from object javascript es6

Tags: javascript, object

```
  let parameters = {
    "lifespanCount": 3,
    "parameters": {
      "fields": {
        "date.original": {
          "stringValue": "tomorrow",
          "kind": "stringValue"
        },
        "duration.original": {
          "stringValue": "3 days",
          "kind": "stringValue"
        },
        "date": {
          "structValue": {
            "fields": {
              "sys.date.recent.original": {
                "stringValue": "tomorrow",
                "kind": "stringValue"
              },
              "sys.date.original": {
                "stringValue": "tomorrow",
                "kind": "stringValue"
              },
              "sys.date": {
                "stringValue": "2018-12-11T12:00:00-05:00",
                "kind": "stringValue"
              },
              "sys.date.recent": {
                "stringValue": "2018-12-11T12:00:00-05:00",
                "kind": "stringValue"
              },
              "sys.date.partial": {
                "stringValue": "2018-12-11T12:00:00-05:00",
                "kind": "stringValue"
              },
              "sys.date.partial.original": {
                "stringValue": "tomorrow",
                "kind": "stringValue"
              }
            }
          },
          "kind": "structValue"
        },
        "yes.original": {
          "stringValue": "",
          "kind": "stringValue"
        },
        "duration": {
          "structValue": {
            "fields": {
              "sys.duration.object": {
                "structValue": {
                  "fields": {}
                },
                "kind": "structValue"
              },
              "sys.duration": {
                "structValue": {
                  "fields": {
                    "unit": {
                      "stringValue": "day",
                      "kind": "stringValue"
                    },
                    "amount": {
                      "numberValue": 3,
                      "kind": "numberValue"
                    }
                  }
                },
                "kind": "structValue"
              },
              "sys.duration.original": {
                "stringValue": "3 days",
                "kind": "stringValue"
              }
            }
          },
          "kind": "structValue"
        },
        "location.original": {
          "stringValue": "china",
          "kind": "stringValue"
        },
        "location": {
          "structValue": {
            "fields": {
              "sys.geo-country.original": {
                "stringValue": "china",
                "kind": "stringValue"
              },
              "sys.geo-country.object": {
                "structValue": {
                  "fields": {}
                },
                "kind": "structValue"
              },
              "sys.geo-country": {
                "stringValue": "China",
                "kind": "stringValue"
              }
            }
          },
          "kind": "structValue"
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

From above object what is the best way to get values like,

```
let date = parameters.fields['date'].structValue.fields['sys.date'].stringValue;
let country = parameters.fields['location'].structValue.fields['sys.geo-country'].stringValue
```

what can be a common function so, anyone can access value directly if pass object and key
i have tried `object.values()`, `object.keys()` have also read MDN docs but not getting much more regarding this. what my aim is to get the value from object when i pass any key with object.

Comment: Why not write a function to extract this for you?

Comment: not sure what you are asking exactly. What exactly would you want the user to give you as input?

Comment: You could write a function that split the input by `.` and looped through each element until it drilled down to the base, or you could just use a package that already contained the function you want, e.g. lodash. I don't like re-inventing the wheel if I don't have to.

Comment: i want to get values `parameters.fields['date'].structValue.fields['sys.date'].stringValue;` but this is too long sting what is best es6 function to extract this value

Comment: There is no shortcut to get to a nested object's property.

Comment: @DrewSchneider my aim is not to do with any dependency, only javascript

Comment: Each piece of the method you're already using (that you're saying is "too long") is simply defining what you're looking for. I don't see how any of that could possibly be shortened, outside of JavaScript magically guessing what you're looking for. Perhaps there's a formatting standard to your object that you're trying to bypass, but if so, you'd really need to point it out.

Answer (score 0):

Based purely on your two examples, the easiest way seems to be:

```
function getString(paramField, structField) {
  if (parameters.fields[paramField] && parameters.fields[paramField].structValue.fields[structField]) {
  return parameters.fields[paramField].structValue.fields[structField].stringValue;
  } 
  return '';
}
```

Maybe some additional checks are in order, depending on the likelihood of other variance to the structure.

Then the calling code can just be:

```
let date = getString('date', 'sys.date');
```

Comment: i would not apply for all, not a global solution

Comment: @NikhilSavaliya as folks have siad in the comments, there is no global solution.  The best  you can do is helper methods like the above.